# org.junit.runners does not exist in June 5

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit4, junit5

I am migrating from junit 4 to 5 and I see that the following packages do not exist.

org.junit.rules.TestRule,   org.junit.runner.Description;  org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

```
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class InMemoryDatabasePopulator implements TestRule {
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InMemoryDatabasePopulator.class);

  private final JdbcConnectionPool connectionPool;

  public InMemoryDatabasePopulator(String databaseName) {
    this.connectionPool = new H2ConnectionPoolBuilder(databaseName).build();
  }

  @Override
  public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
    String root = description.getTestClass().getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/");
    try {
         return new InMemoryPopulatorStatement(base, description, root, 
          connectionPool.getConnection());
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          logger.error(String.format("Unable to apply instructions[setup=%s, cleanup=%s]",
                 description.getAnnotation(InMemorySetup.class), description.getAnnotation(
                         InMemoryCleanup.class)), e);
     }
      // if we arrive here, we failed setup but we will let the test method itself execute.
      return base;
   }
 }
```

Do you have any suggestions on what your Statement and Description replacements would be?

this is my gradle.  I replaced junit dependencies with jupiter library

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':my project')

    api('ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-base:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'commons-lang', module: 'commons-lang'
    }

    api group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-structures-v251', version: '2.2'
    api group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-structures-v231', version: '2.2'
    api group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-structures-v23', version: '2.2'
    api group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-structures-v21', version: '2.2'

    api('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9') {
        exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', module: 'xmlbeans'
    }
    api group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '3.0.0'
    api group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
    implementation group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.0.1'
    api('org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.6.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.geronimo.specs', module: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
        exclude group: 'javax.xml.stream', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-impl'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'stax2-api'
    }

    api('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2') { 
        exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }

    api ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3')
    api ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3')
    api('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.12.3')

    api('org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.geronimo.specs', module: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
        exclude group: 'javax.xml.stream', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-impl'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'stax2-api'
    }
    api('org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:2.6.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.geronimo.specs', module: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
        exclude group: 'javax.xml.stream', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'joda-time', module: 'joda-time'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.santuario', module: 'xmlsec'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-impl'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'stax2-api'
    }
    implementation group: 'org.apache.santuario', name: 'xmlsec', version: '1.5.2'

    // Hibernate dependencies
    
    api('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.logging', module: 'jboss-logging'
        exclude group:'javax.xml.bind' , module:'jaxb-api'
        exclude group:'org.jvnet.staxex' , module:'stax-ex'
        exclude group:'com.sun.xml.fastinfoset' , module:'FastInfoset'
        exclude group:'net.bytebuddy' , module:'byte-buddy'
        exclude group:'org.javassist' , module:'javassist'
    }    
    api group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.20.0-GA'
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.logging', name: 'jboss-logging', version: '3.3.1.Final'

    
    api group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: springVersion
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: springVersion
    api('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:1.0.5.RELEASE'){
        exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-webmvc'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-mapper-asl'
    }
    api group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion
    api group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: springVersion
    api group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: springVersion
    api group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: springVersion
    api group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: '5.1.20.RELEASE'
    
    // Uses Castor for XML
    api group: 'org.codehaus.castor', name: 'castor', version: '1.2'
    // Castor needs this
    implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.11.0'

    api group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: springVersion
    api group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: springVersion
    
    api (group: 'org.jadira.usertype', name: 'usertype.core', version: '6.0.1.GA'){
       exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
       exclude group: 'org.javassist', module: 'javassist'
       exclude group: 'org.hibernate.common', module: 'hibernate-commons-annotations'
       exclude group: 'org.jboss.logging', module: 'jboss-logging'
       exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
    }
    
    api('org.drools:drools-core:5.5.0.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    
    api('org.drools:drools-compiler:5.5.0.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler' , module: 'ecj'
    }
    
    implementation "org.codehaus.janino:janino:2.5.16"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4"
    
    api group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
    api group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.2.6'
    implementation group: 'commons-discovery', name: 'commons-discovery', version: '0.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jaxrpc-api', version: '1.1'
    implementation group: 'wsdl4j', name: 'wsdl4j', version: '1.6.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis', version: '1.4'
    implementation('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.2.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-aop'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-context'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-oxm'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-webmvc'
    }
    implementation('jaxen:jaxen:1.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'xml-apis', module: 'xml-apis'
        exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'
        exclude group: 'xom', module: 'xom'
        exclude group: 'maven-plugins', module: 'maven-cobertura-plugin'
        exclude group: 'maven-plugins', module: 'maven-findbugs-plugin'
        exclude group: 'jdom', module: 'jdom'
    }
    
    provided group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.2.0'
    implementation group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.2.0' // TODO this is provided. Not sure it matters
    
    implementation group: 'integrisign', name: 'websign', version: '12.0.R1416'
    implementation group: 'org.rxtx', name: 'rxtx', version: '2.1.7'
    implementation group: 'com.topaz', name: 'sigplus', version: '2.68'
    
    api group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    implementation (group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '2.3.3'){
        exclude group:'jakarta.activation' ,  module:'jakarta.activation-api'
        exclude group:'com.sun.mail' , module:'jakarta.mail'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj' , module: 'saaj-impl'
        exclude group: 'jakarta.xml.soap', module:'jakarta.xml.soap-api'
    }

    testImplementation project(path: ':myproject', configuration: 'tests')
    testImplementation (group: 'org.dbunit', name: 'dbunit', version: '2.4.5'){
         exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.7.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.7.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.12.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '3.12.2'
    testImplementation (group: 'org.jmock', name: 'jmock-junit5', version: '2.12.0') {
        exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy', module: 'byte-buddy'
        exclude group: 'org.junit.jupiter', module: 'junit-jupiter-api'
        exclude group: 'org.junit.platform', module: 'junit-platform-launcher'
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis', module: 'objenesis'
    }
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine
    testImplementation (group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.7.2')
    {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }


    testImplementation (group: 'org.jmock', name: 'jmock-imposters', version: '2.12.0'){
        exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy', module: 'byte-buddy'
        exclude group: 'org.junit.jupiter', module: 'junit-jupiter-api'
        exclude group: 'org.junit.platform', module: 'junit-platform-launcher'
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis', module: 'objenesis'
    }

    testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}"

    // for h2 goodness
    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.188'
    implementation (group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version: '1.5.1'){
         exclude group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', module: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api'
         exclude group: 'org.jvnet.staxex', module: 'stax-ex'
         exclude group: 'org.jvnet.mimepull', module: 'mimepull'
    }    
 
    api group: 'org.glassfish.metro', name: 'webservices-rt', version: '2.4.4'
    api group: 'org.glassfish.metro', name: 'webservices-api', version: '2.4.4'
}
```

Comment: Most probably you have your dependencies wrong. Please show your pom.xml or Gradle file.

Comment: Thank you @johanneslink for the reply. That is my gradle file.

Comment: You're explicitly excluding the old junit with `exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'`. That's probably the reason why you don't see it. The next question is: Why do you want to switch over to JUnit 5 (I assume you mean Jupiter) when you still want to use all the JUnit 4 test mechanisms?

Comment: I need to migrate all junit 4 to junit 5. That's why I can't find a replacement for those libraries or any suggestions

Comment: The equivalent to JUnit 4 rules are Jupiter extensions. You’ll have to migrate your rules